# Celery - working with task return values at views.py

Tags: python, django, task, celery

I want to get the value of a celery task result, the value of the actual return statement of my task and not the task_id itself!
I don't understand how to accomplish this assuming the following example:

views.py

```
def call_my_task(request)
user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    example_form = ExampleForm(data=request.POST)
    if example_form.is_valid():
            my_input = str(example_form.data.get("user_input"))
            check_input = validate_input.apply_async(kwargs={"my_input": my_input})
            check_input.get(timeout=30, interval=1)
```

tasks.py

```
@celery_app.task(name="Check example input", ignore_result=False)
def validate_input(my_input):
    check = subprocess.Popen("some cmd" + ' ' + my_input, shell=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()
    return check
```

Doing it like so always gives me the task_id at my views.py and does not tell me the value of
"return check"
The command called at the celery task can only return true or false
and exactly this true or false value (as str) Is what I want to have to work further at my views.py with.

Can smb. help me out?

Comment: show us your celery config

Answer (score 2):

Okay just got it working.
Simply fetch the return value by using check_input.info please also see: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.result

> ->  property info
> Task return value.

You can then just do something like: if check_input.info == str('true'):